# How to share methods across multiple Android activities types

Tags: java, android

I'm building and **Android** application using **ActionBarSherlock**.

I have **multipe types** of activities:

- SherlockFragmentActivity
- SherlockMapActivity
- SherlockActivity

I want **all** my activities to share **common methods** to follow an internal workflow of screens.

If I create a `Workflow` class that extends `SherlockFragmentActivity` then my `MapActivity does` not work anymore.
If I create a `Worflow` class that extends `SherlockMapActivity` then my `TutorialActivity` does not work anymore (because it's using a `new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());`.

Do note that the common methods I want are also running `startActivity()`.

I know Java cannot have a class that extends more than one class, so how should I go about this?

```
public class Workflow extends SherlockMapActivity {

protected void goMain() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

    // ...
}

public class TutorialActivity extends Workflow {
    // ...
    // new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    // ...
}

public class GameActivity extends Workflow {
    // ...
    // MapView
    // ...
}
```

I also want to share code like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
}
```

Comment: Use abstract classes and interfaces ;) extend and implement those in your project

Comment: @user1281750 Could you elaborate in an answer please?

Comment: I would like my code to be in `Workflow` class and not to be repeated in activities.

Comment: @shkschneider : what about [Application Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) by which you can share variables or methods to whole appliction.you have try it?

Comment: Application Class cannot handle everything I would like (AFAIK)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom `Activity` class and extend that in your activities.

So for example:

```
public abstract class DerivedActivityA extends Activity implements CustomInterfaceA {

    // ... your code here
}

public abstract class DerivedActivityB extends DerivedActivityA implements CustomInterfaceB {

    // ... your code here
}
```

If you have to implement multiple interfaces then use abstract classes like I did above and implement interfaces.

**Edit:** 
If I get it right `SectionsPagerAdapter` is just an adapter so you can compose it in one of your classes as a field.

**Edit2:**
You can't extend two classes and you can't compose an `Activity` into another one so you either have to write things for yourself or extract the functionality you need from your third party library.

Comment: I face the problem that MapActivity does not go along with a SectionsPagerAdapter

Comment: `SectionsPagerAdapter` need a `FragmentManager` which is given by `getSupportFragmentManager()` from ActionBarSherlock

Comment: So so can use this method in your derived class to give it to your composed adapter, right?

Comment: The class need to extend `SherlockFragmentActivity` to be able to. But I need `SherlockMapActivity` on one activity...

Comment: I can't get it to work. I create my activities as extending `DerivedActivityB` but if `Activity` is `SherlockFragmentActivity` how could my activity also extends `SherlockMapActivity`?..

Comment: You extend SherlockMapActivity in your abstract class and in that class you compose your adapter too.

Comment: I cant build ActionBarSherlock's `SectionsPagerAdapter` without extending `SherlockFragmentActivity`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19588/discussion-between-shkschneider-and-adam-arold)